# Fakeraid partition missing (not mapped as a device on boot) after upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: partition, raid, device-mapper

I have a RAID-0 volume with an NTFS partition that has worked fine for years on my dual-boot system (readable and writable by both Windows and Linux).

Today after doing a `do-release-upgrade -d` to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 (from Ubuntu 20.04), this filesystem isn't showing up in Ubuntu. The problem seems to be around device mapping; here's what I've tried/found so far:

- It still works fine in Windows. I don't think anything changed on the disks.
- An NTFS partition on a different disk (non-RAID) still mounts and works fine.
- Booting into the old kernel (via grub) doesn't fix it (and seems to cause other problems).
- I thought my setup was "hardware RAID" because I configured it via a BIOS boot screen titled "Intel Matrix Storage Manager", but I guess this is actually "fakeraid".
- The RAID volume shows up in the Disks utility (as `/dev/dm-0`, and this file exists) with no partitions, just "unallocated space".
- The RAID volume shows up in GParted (as `/dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid`, and this file exists) with an ntfs partition named `/dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid1` (i.e. the volume name with a `1` appended), but that device file does not exist. The only file in `/dev/mapper/` is `isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid`.

Here's the relevant part of `sudo fdisk -l`. (`sda`,`sdb`,`sdc` are the disks in the RAID array.)

```
Disk /dev/sda: 596.17 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD6401AALS-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x15967f5e

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 3750772735 3750770688  1.7T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT


Disk /dev/sdb: 596.17 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD6401AALS-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2a0921b8


Disk /dev/sdc: 596.17 GiB, 640135028736 bytes, 1250263728 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD6401AALS-0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2a0921bf


Disk /dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid: 1.75 TiB, 1920398131200 bytes, 3750777600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 131072 bytes / 393216 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x15967f5e

Device                                     Boot Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid-part1       2048 3750772735 3750770688  1.7T  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

The file `/dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid-part1` (note the `-part1`) doesn't exist either.

**I'm slightly worried by the fact that `/dev/sda1` shows up**, since (if my assumptions are correct) we should only be looking for partition tables on the combined volume, not directly on a single disk in the array. **The file `/dev/sda1` exists**, and `sudo ntfs-3g.probe --readwrite /dev/sda1` reports "NTFS signature is missing". Maybe the system is finding my partition table on `sda`, even though that data is just part of a RAID stripe, and creating `dev/sda1` based on it. I can imagine this causing some kind of name collision when the identical "real" partition table on the RAID volume is encountered.

FWIW, `hdparm -z /dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid` outputs:

```
/dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid:
 re-reading partition table
 BLKRRPART failed: Invalid argument
```

That's pretty much where I'm stuck! How can I fix this? Thanks in advance for any suggestions - even obvious ones, since I don't really know what I'm doing.

Some other notes (likely irrelevant):

- Yesterday I upgraded from `nvidia-driver-390` to `nvidia-driver-470` via the gui "Additional Drivers" tool and had [this problem](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473057) where it switched me from a `-generic` to an `-oracle` kernel that didn't recognize my networking hardware. Wanting a newer (generic) kernel is what motivated me to do the distribution upgrade.
- I wanted to do a clean install from the Ubuntu 22.04 Live CD (which I verified against the published checksum after burning), but it fails to boot ("Failed to start CUPS scheduler" after several minutes).
- The `do-release-upgrade` went smoothly AFAICT except for an error about a handful of "mpi" packages at the end. Afterwards, `apt` commands were failing, with dpkg complaining that these packages were "not configured yet". I fixed this by reinstalling `openmpi-bin` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62464086).

---

More output as requested in comments:

```
# lsblk -M -f
    NAME
     FSTYPE FSVER LABEL         UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS

[after a bunch of loop devices related to /snap/...]

┌┈▶ sda
     isw_ra 1.2.0                                                                   
├┈▶ sdb
     isw_ra 1.2.0                                                                   
└┬▶ sdc
     isw_ra 1.2.0                                                                   
 └┈┈isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid
                                                                                    
    sdd
│                                                                                   
    ├─sdd1
│    ntfs         OCZ Vertex 4  1A7643E57643C06D                       58.6G    69% /mnt/WinC
    ├─sdd2
│    ntfs                       129E918C9E9168CD                                    
    ├─sdd3
│                                                                                   
    ├─sdd5
│    ext4   1.0                 5b327639-85e6-4f6a-ac79-743cfedf3e29   10.8G    64% /
    └─sdd6
     swap   1                   b601da00-767d-4e50-b62a-0b832992599c                [SWAP]

# partx /dev/mapper/ is isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid
partx: bad usage
Try 'partx --help' for more information.

# partx /dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid   
NR START        END    SECTORS SIZE NAME UUID
 1  2048 3750772735 3750770688 1.7T      15967f5e-01

# partx /dev/sda                            
NR START        END    SECTORS SIZE NAME UUID
 1  2048 3750772735 3750770688 1.7T      15967f5e-01
```

Comment: Is it truly "hardware" RAID? It looks very much like so-called "fakeraid" where there's no RAID controller to be found anywhere and the entire system relies on Windows drivers to actually perform the RAID processing in software. In that case it'd be entirely expected for the OS to see raw disks and build up a software RAID array through them, like Linux is doing via dm-raid.

Comment: @user1686 I guess this "Intel Matrix Storage Manager" stuff is indeed fakeraid - weird! I edited the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the output of `lsblk -M -f` and of `partx /dev/mapper/ is isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid`? Do you have the kpartx tool (multipath-tools) installed?

Comment: @user1686 added. And yep, I have kpartx.

Comment: The `partx` output seems consistent with my theory about the system using partition data it finds on sda before finding that same data in the right place on the RAID volume. I wonder if I could somehow disable the part where it finds/creates sda1.

Comment: Well, at least temporarily, you can use `kpartx` to set up/detect partitions on top of your RAID device – the kernel doesn't support "native" partitions on mapper devices (fdisk just makes up some device names to show), but kpartx will set up mapper-based partitions instead – however I don't really know what the setup was like before upgrading, whether it was detecting your RAID via devicemapper or in some other way, so I can't really direct towards fixing it properly.

Comment: But in general, note that fdisk performs its own parsing of partition tables and its output doesn't necessarily reflect "reality" i.e. what the kernel has detected. If there's no sda1 in `lsblk` or in your /dev, then there is no sda1 – ignore what fdisk says. (I wouldn't expect the partitions to be detected on sda anyway, because it also has the IMSM array metadata that should be detected first and prevent accidental direct usage.)

Comment: Cool, thanks for your time! Fwiw, I'm pretty sure the setup was the same before upgrading (because I rember the /dev/mapper/isw... file). Also, there *is* a device file `/dev/sda1` (i.e. `ls /dev` shows it)! I should've made that clearer in my post.

Comment: ...at least, I could've sworn `/dev/sda1` existed when I was investigating yesterday. Now it doesn't, and `kpartx -a /dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid` (which I hadn't tried until now) works - it creates `/dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid1`, and my old fstab entry (which references the partition by a UUID) mounts it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

With credits to u1686_grawity, there is a simple extra step we should do now: use `kpartx` to detect partitions on built drive.

```bash
sudo kpartx -a /dev/mapper/isw_dfjaifidah_KarlsRaid
```

I did this (of course, with my own jMicron fakeRAID) on my system and it was fine:

```bash
hopungo@hopungo-pc:~$ sudo kpartx -l /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 
jmicron_GRAID1 : 0 7813722112 /dev/mapper/jmicron_GRAID 2048
```

And the second part is to make this command run automatically on system start, which covered in another topics (but the info is outdated). I will add my solution here after I'll be sure it's working.